# how to load customer by email in magento2?

Tags: magento2, customer

In magento 1.9, I used `loadByEmail` method from resource model.

But in magento2 in `Magento\Customer\Model` I see `loadByEmail` method. Customer factory, as well as customer entity which I get from quote, returns `Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer` which does not have this method.

Also `CustomerRepository` have only `getById` method.

how to load customer entity by email ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Magento 2 you need to use the `get` method from the `Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface` service contract class.

```
public function get($email, $websiteId = null);
```

Comment: What is this get method returns?.Can we get the entityId by the return of this method

Comment: Do you know why `$customer = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($email,'email')` not works? It returns null.

Comment: Had to use \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory  because when the email was not found instead of returning false or null it was breaking. error: "No such entity with email = xxx, websiteId = 1" . Any suggestions?

Comment: @Mehdi Surround it with a try-catch Block    `try {
            return $this->customerRepository->get($email, 1);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return null;
        }`

Comment: @LucScu the Method you are searching for is called `loadByEmail`  for ` Magento\Customer\Model\Customer` class

Answer (score 8):

It is working fine, please use below code-

```
$CustomerModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer');
$CustomerModel->setWebsiteId(1); **//Here 1 means Store ID**
$CustomerModel->loadByEmail($customerEmail);
$userId = $CustomerModel->getId();
```

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE and thanks for your contribution. However, using the object manager  is discouraged and even working directly with the  models is considered deprecated by Magento. Best practise is using the service contracts (here: `CustomerRepository::get()`) and in this case they do what's needed, so there is no reason not to use them.

Comment: Its not working for me

Comment: setWebsiteId method is for set Store Id not Website ID, Really?

Comment: perfect answer!!! +1 made my day :)